# Query a mysql database using php and display a temporary table that shows record and extra columns that include calculated data from the table fields

Tags: php, html, mysql, querying

Student developer here working on an assignment that involves php and sql. The objective of the assignment is as follows: collect user data through a form and use php to validate and insert
information into a mysql table. The table that is storing user information has strictly four fields, firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, birthdate just as the form has four fields. Provide the
user with a link on the form page that takes them to another page which displays a temporary table of all the users that have submitted their information through this form. In addition
to this data it should also display a few more fields including:

1. the area code as a sub string
2. eligibility status (eligibility status is yes if the area code is 425) otherwise no
3. birth month
4. birthstone
   The birth month and birthstone should be pulled from a two dimensional array using the sub string function and the date of birth fields to accomplish this.
   January Garnet
   February Amethyst
   March Aquamarine
   April Diamond
   May Emerald
   June Pearl
   July Ruby
   August Peridot
   September Sapphire
   October Opal
   November Topaz
   December Tanzanite
5. At the top of the temporary table is a statement that says "As of today, (current date should be displayed), The following participants are registered.
   I have managed to validate the data and insert it into a table. Beyond that is where I am having trouble, starting from querying the database to display the temporary table. How do I return
   the data that's in a table and how do I display it? Should I make a table using HTML and then display database information in that table? If so, how do I go about doing this?

I am not quite sure where to start, though I have tried to retrieve the data from the database and display it. I tried to use mysqli_fetch_assoc to retrieve some data, I managed to retrieve some of it but I do not know how to display it the way the assignment is asking.

```
<?php
  $dbConnect = @mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password")
or die("<p>Unable to connect to the database server.</p>" . "<p>Error code " .     mysqli_connect_errno() . ": " . mysqli_connect_error()) . "</p>";
  $dbName = 'Competition';
  // selects the database
  $QueryResult =   mysqli_select_db($dbConnect, $dbName);
  if (!$QueryResult) {
    echo "cannot connect to this database";
  }
  $TableName = "Competitors";
  $sqlString = "SELECT * FROM $TableName";
  $QueryResult = @mysqli_query($dbConnect, $sqlString)
    or die("<p>Unable to execute the query.</p>" . "<p>Error code " . mysqli_connect_errno() .     ": " . mysqli_connect_error()) . "</p>";
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($QueryResult)) {
    $FirstName = $row['firstName'];
    $LastName = $row['lastName'];
    $PhoneNumber = $row['phone'];
    $Birthdate =  $row['birthday'];
    echo $FirstName . $LastName . $PhoneNumber . $Birthdate . "<br>";
  }
  // closing the connection with the database server
  mysqli_close($dbConnect);
```

Comment: you can remove the selection of the database and instead add it to the connection string, this would increase at least the speed

Comment: your can caalculaten directly in mysql or in php, but ususally you would add the "new" calculated columns in the select

Comment: _"Should I make a table using HTML and then display database information in that table? If so, how do I go about doing this?"_ - you come up with the rough HTML structure you will need to display this data. Then you figure out which parts are "static", and which you need to output again for every record. The static parts go before and after your loop over the data, and the code that is common for each record, goes inside the loop ...